# Process json logs with Grafana/loki

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have set up Grafana, Prometheus and loki (2.6.1) as follows on my kubernetes (1.21) cluster:

```bash
helm upgrade --install promtail grafana/promtail -n monitoring -f monitoring/promtail.yaml
helm upgrade --install prom prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring --values monitoring/prom.yaml
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki -n monitoring --values monitoring/loki.yaml
```

with:

```yaml
# monitoring/loki.yaml
loki:
  schemaConfig:
    configs:
    - from: 2020-09-07
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: s3
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: loki_index_
        period: 24h

  storageConfig:
    aws:
      s3: s3://eu-west-3/cluster-loki-logs
    boltdb_shipper:
      shared_store: filesystem
      active_index_directory: /var/loki/index
      cache_location: /var/loki/cache
      cache_ttl: 168h

# monitoring/promtail.yaml
config:
  serverPort: 80
  clients:
    - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

# monitoring/prom.yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    serviceMonitorSelector: {}
    serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
      matchLabels:
        monitored: "true"

grafana:
  sidecar:
    datasources:
      defaultDatasourceEnabled: true
  additionalDataSources:
    - name: Loki
      type: loki
      url: http://loki.monitoring:3100
```

I get data from my containers, but, whenever I have a container logging in json format, I can't get access to the nested fields:

```
{app="product", namespace="api-dev"} | unpack | json
```

Yields:

[image]

My aim is, for example, to filter by `log.severity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72661706/1599054), it occurs to be a `promtail` scraping issue.

The current (`promtail-6.3.1` / 2.6.1) helm chart default is to have [`cri`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/cri/) as pipeline's stage, which expects this kind of logs:

```
"2019-04-30T02:12:41.8443515Z stdout xx message"
```

I should have use [`docker`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/docker/), which expects json, consequently, my `promtail.yaml` changed to:

```
config:
  serverPort: 80
  clients:
    - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
  snippets:
    pipelineStages:
      - docker: {}
```